# What is the Windows equivalent file for .bashrc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, environment-variables

I am trying to install eventmachine as follows:

```
gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'
```

I get the following problem:

```
D:\rails_workspace\rubytime>gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... no
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for winsock.h... yes
checking for main() in -lkernel32... yes
checking for main() in -lrpcrt4... yes
checking for main() in -lgdi32... yes
checking for main() in -lssl... no
creating Makefile

make
generating rubyeventmachine-i386-mingw32.def
compiling binder.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from project.h:137:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:138:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
em.h:91:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:92:76: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93:56: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:95:57: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:96:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:97:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:98:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:101:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:106:42: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:123:45: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:132:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:45:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:46:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:49:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:62:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:63:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:64:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:99:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:100:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:102:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
compiling cmain.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from project.h:137:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:138:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
em.h:91:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:92:76: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93:56: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:95:57: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:96:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:97:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:98:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:101:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:106:42: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:123:45: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:132:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:45:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:46:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:49:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:62:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:63:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:64:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:99:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:100:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:102:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:98:71: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:109:122: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:119:79: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:129:83: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:260:85: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:270:84: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:280:88: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:290:51: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:300:70: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:320:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:546:70: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:669:68: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp: In function 'int evma_send_file_data_to_connection(long unsigned int, const char*)':
cmain.cpp:752:6: error: cannot convert 'stat*' to '_stati64*' for argument '2' to 'int _fstati64(int, _stati64*)'
make: *** [cmain.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/ext/gem_make.out
```

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447590/thin-eventmachine-non-root-installation-problem) where I found some information but don't know how to do that in Windows

Please help me how to resolve this issues in windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need .bashrc, add environment variable instead. To set an environment variable(which is equivalent to the solution described in the post) do that right click on My computer, select properties -> advanced and then environment variables. Create a new value with name the name you need and value equivalent to the one you give it in linux(please note that $USER will not work. Either type your username or use %USERNAME%). I am not sure this will fix your problem I am just telling you how to perform action equivalent to the one described in the answer you link to. Also the way to set environment variable may differ a little depending on your windows version.